# How to delete a record with all relevant records in prisma

Tags: prisma

I know that there are some sections related to my question in [the documentation of prisma-client](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client):

- [deleting objects](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/writing-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc6/#deleting-objects)
- [updating and deleting many records](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/writing-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc6/#updating-and-deleting-many-records)

However, I can't understand that how can I delete a record with all its related records in (JavaScript) prisma-client.

For example, my [datamodel](https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.25/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-MONGO-knun/) is something like this:

```
type Board {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "BoardOwnershipRelation")
  title: String!
  description: String
  taskGroups: [TaskGroup!]!
}

type TaskGroup {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "TaskGroupOwnershipRelation")
  board: Board!
  title: String!
  description: String
  precedence: Int
  tasks: [Task!]!
}

type Task {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "TaskOwnershipRelation")
  taskGroup: TaskGroup!
  title: String!
  description: String
  dueDate: DateTime
  precedence: Int
  items: [TaskItem!]!
  assignedTo: [User!]! @relation(name: "AssignmentRelation")
}

type TaskItem {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "TaskItemOwnershipRelation")
  task: Task!
  title: String!
  description: String
  checked: Boolean!
  precedence: Int
}
```

***How*** can I delete a Board with all its related TaskGroups, Tasks, and TaskItems ?!

**Edit**:

I've recently tried this solution, which also works well.

```
// e.g. this is in my GraphQL resolvers async function...

await prisma.deleteManyTaskItems({
  task: {
    taskGroup: {
      board: {
        id: boardId
      }
    }
  }
});

await prisma.deleteManyTasks({
  taskGroup: {
    board: {
      id: boardId
    }
  }
});

await prisma.deleteManyTaskGroups({
  board: {
    id: boardId
  }
});

return await prisma.deleteBoard({ id: boardId });
```

But, **is there any better solution for my issue ???**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `onDelete` argument of the `@relation` directive to specify what happens when you delete an entity ([documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-MYSQL-knul/#the-@relation-directive))

You only have to change your datamodel like so:

```
type Board {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "BoardOwnershipRelation")
  title: String!
  description: String
  taskGroups: [TaskGroup!]! @relation(name: "BoardTaskGroups" onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type TaskGroup {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "TaskGroupOwnershipRelation")
  board: Board! @relation(name: "BoardTaskGroups")
  title: String!
  description: String
  precedence: Int
  tasks: [Task!]! @relation(name: "TaskGroupsTask" onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type Task {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "TaskOwnershipRelation")
  taskGroup: TaskGroup! @relation(name: "TaskGroupsTask")
  title: String!
  description: String
  dueDate: DateTime
  precedence: Int
  items: [TaskItem!]! @relation(name: "TaskTaskItem" onDelete: CASCADE)
  assignedTo: [User!]! @relation(name: "AssignmentRelation")
}

type TaskItem {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  owner: User! @relation(name: "TaskItemOwnershipRelation")
  task: Task! @relation(name: "TaskTaskItem")
  title: String!
  description: String
  checked: Boolean!
  precedence: Int
}
```

And then delete your Board. All the other deletions will be done by Prisma